# Finite expectation - Difference between these two statements?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

**Main Question:** Let $\{X_n, n=0,1,2...\}$ be a stochastic process. How are following two statements different?

\begin{align} 
E[|X_n|]<\infty \text{ for all } n
\end{align}

and

\begin{align} 
\text{ for some } M<\infty, E[|X_n|]\leq M\text{ for all } n
\end{align}

**A bit more background and my idea:** If $X_n$ is a Martingale, we know the first statement holds. However, Martingale Convergence Theorem requires second statement in addition to $X_n$ being a Martingale. Therefore, it seems like two statements are not equivalent but I cannot see the difference.

In the first statement, we do not force an finite upper bound that holds for every $n$. Then, for every $n$ there is an $M_n<\infty$ such that $E[|X_n|]\leq M_n$ and for every $M_n$, there is a $m\neq n$ such that $E[|X_m|]> M_n$. So, for every $n$, there is a finite bound but there is not a single finite value that is true for all $n$. I am not sure if my interpretation is correct. Like I said, I cannot see the difference between two statements and that's the explanation I came up with but I am not convinced.

If someone can help me to understand this, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction exists even without any randomness.  Let $x_n = n$.  Then
$|x_n| < \infty$ for all $n$, but there is no $M < \infty$ such that
$|x_n| \le M$ for all $n$.

Comment: That's a very simple way to see it. I guess my interpretation was correct in the first place but I overcomplicated it.